# Tcl/Tk - Memchan - fifo - how to rename fifo as stdout in a tcl/tk application which has Memchan statically linked?

Tags: redirect, tcl, stdout

I cross posted this question on comp.lang.tcl.

I am developing a `Tcl/Tk` application (call it `rs`) and I want to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a text box in my `Tcl/Tk` application. I am using `Memchan` to achieve this (I statically linked `Memchan` into my application). But I am unable to rename the `fifo` channel I created as `stderr`. (The same thing holds true for `stdout` too)

For example, in the following snippet, I am closing `stderr` and then opening `fifo` as `stderr` but fifo channel remains named as `fifo0` not as `stderr`.

```
 $ rs
 rs> package require Memchan
 2.3
 rs> chan names
 stdin stdout stderr
 rs> close stderr
 rs> chan names
 stdin stdout
 rs> set stderr [fifo]
 fifo0
 rs> chan names
 fifo0 stdin stdout
```

I expected `stderr` instead of `fifo0` when I typed in the last of the `chan names` command.

But when I use `tclsh8.5` the above sequence produces the desired effect i.e `fifo` is renamed as `stderr`

```
 $ tclsh8.5
 % package req Memchan
 2.3
 % chan names
 stdin stdout stderr
 % close stderr
 % chan names
 stdin stdout
 % set stderr [fifo]
 fifo0
 % chan names
 stderr stdin stdout
```

Note: no `fifo0` but we get the desired `stderr`.

Can someone point out how to reproduce the behavior in `tclsh8.5` in my `Tcl/Tk` application `rs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since memchan doesn't produce channels backed up by a file descriptor, it can't replace the standard channels (which always correspond to FDs 0, 1 and 2).

Comment: Then how does this work in `tclsh`? What is the best possible way to redirect `stdout` or `stderr` to text widget?

Comment: But why would you? Isn't it simpler to just redefine `[puts]` or use a custom function to do output (which will go to that text widget)?

Comment: @kostix I have a `tcl` application and I am writing a `tk` gui on top of that to provide graphical interface for the `tcl` commands. My requirement is: The output of the `tcl` commands (when they are fired from `tk` menu) to appear on the text widget. I tried the `stdout` redirect to a file as described in the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3995) by calling the `proc stdout` function at the start of my script. But it does not redirect the output to a file but rather sends the output to the `tcl` console.

Comment: @Anand, may be it's possible to load your ready-made tcl program (I assume it's a bunch of Tcl scripts) into a child interp which has its `[puts]` command aliased to a special proc in your parent interp which arranges for the output to go to that text widget?
A quick demo: http://pastebin.com/e4d7hYTE (note that `[interp eval]` is able to evaluate whatever you tell it to, like `[source]`ing a script file etc).