# tcl/tk - Can we redirect the tcl stdout to a socket?

Tags: sockets, redirect, tcl

I am trying to redirect my `stdout` and `stderr` output to a text widget and I tried `Memchan` to do it and it did [not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965026/tcl-tk-memchan-fifo-how-to-rename-fifo-as-stdout-in-a-tcl-tk-application-wh).

The next option we are looking at is using sockets. Can we redirect `tcl` `stdout` to a socket? If yes, can you provide an example code to demonstrate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run in a subprocess? It's easy if you can:

```
socket -server accept 12345   ;# pick your own port number...
proc accept {channel host port} {
    exec [info nameofexecutable] realScript.tcl \
            <@$channel >@$channel 2>@$channel &
}
vwait forever                 ;# run the event loop to serve sockets...
```

This starts a Tcl subprocess executing `realScript.tcl` for each incoming socket connection, and arranges for stdin (`<@`) stdout (`>@`) and stderr (`2>@`) to be redirected to the socket. It also runs the subprocess in the background (final `&`) so that it doesn't block incoming connections. (You might want to check `$host` and `$port` for acceptability before running the subprocess.)

What's even better, in the subprocess Tcl will still auto-detect that it's dealing with sockets; the `fconfigure` command will be able to see the socket configuration (even if it can't change what port its talking to, of course).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "redirect my stdout"? Do you mean, when you do a `puts foo` you want that to go to a socket? If so, simply replace the default `puts` command with your own which writes to the socket. You do that by renaming `puts` to something else, then creating your own proc named `puts`. Then, your proc will use the renamed command to do the actual I/O, but you can interject the socket as an argument.